# Can I use 2133MHz RAM on MSI Z170 Pro Carbon?

Tags: memory, computer-building

I would like to assemble my PC and I want to know if it is possible to mount a kit of *2133MHz* RAM on **MSI Z170 Pro Carbon** because I found a kit of 16GB.

Comment: Is it [this](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z170-A-PRO.html#hero-overview) motherboard you mean? If so, the most important thing is that the memory is **DDR4**, otherwise it won't fit.

Answer (score 2):

According to MSI motherboard manual yes.

> 4x DDR4 memory slots, support up to 64GB  Supports DDR4 3600(OC)/
>   3200(OC)/ 3000(OC)/ 2800(OC)/ 2600(OC)/ 2400/ 2133 MHz* y Dual channel
>   memory architecture y Supports ECC, un-buffered memory  ECC UDIMM
>   memory (non-ECC mode) y Supports Intel® Extreme Memory Profile (XMP)
>   * Please refer to www.msi.com for more information on compatible memory.

reference link: (page 15)
https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z170A-GAMING-PRO-CARBON#down-manual

You can also check what memory brands/model supported:
https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z170A-GAMING-PRO-CARBON#support-mem-3